# No module named 'cfgrib' / 'ecmwflib'

Tags: python, linux, modulenotfounderror, cfgrib, eccodes

I try to run this script in a SH file this script `python3.6 Scriptfile.py /route`

The script:

```
import os
import xarray as xr
import ecmwflibs
import cfgrib
import sys


data_path = r'/grib' + '/'
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(data_path+'*',engine="cfgrib", combine = 'nested', backend_kwargs={'filter_by_keys': {'stepType': 'accum'}}, concat_dim='step')
```

It returns this erros:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scriptfile.py", line 20, in <module>
    import ecmwflibs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecmwflibs'
```

If I comment the line `import ecmwflibs`, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scriptfile.py", line 20, in <module>
    import cfgrib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cfgrib'
```

The libraries are installed:

```
$ python3.6 -m pip list | egrep "(eccodes|ecmwflib|cfgrib)"
cfgrib                  0.9.10.0
eccodes                 1.2.0
ecmwflibs               0.5.0
pyeccodes               0.1.1
```

The problem it seems to be an incorrect PATH definition? `echo $PATH`

```
/home/XXXX/.local/bin:
/home/XXXX/bin:
/home/XXXX/.local/bin:
/home/XXXX/bin:
/home/XXXX/.local/bin:
/home/XXXX/bin:
/home/XXXX/miniconda3/bin:
/home/XXXX/miniconda3/condabin:
/home/XXXX/.local/bin:
/home/XXXX/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/sbin
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this issue when I tried to re-install ecmwflibs via pip:

```
(my_env) user@server[PY3]:~$ pip install ecmwflibs
Requirement already satisfied: ecmwflibs in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.5.3)
```

I solved the problem by adding to path also /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages, so in your case should be something like

```
/home/XXXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Hope this will solve your issue